# How to parse dialog drawed into SVG file by python? Or maybe better ways to do it?

Tags: python, parsing

The example I drew:

[image]

Exported to SVG and tried svgpathtools, but it returns only

```
[Path(Line(start=(60+60j), end=(60+113.63j))),
 Path(Line(start=(60+118.88j), end=(56.5+111.88j)),
  Line(start=(56.5+111.88j), end=(60+113.63j)),
  Line(start=(60+113.63j), end=(63.5+111.88j)),
  Line(start=(63.5+111.88j), end=(60+118.88j)))]
```

But I need all objects, texts inside and haw it connected.
Maybe there are better ways to do it? Basically, I need simple draw by hand 2 types of blocks, connections, and texts inside. And easy parse it by python.